# Compiler error about control reaches end of non void function

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm getting a compiler error when compiling my code.

The problem is to find the largest prime factor for each of the fixed number of numbers from the user

The error I got -

```
Solution.c: In function ‘largest_prime_factor’:
Solution.c:35:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

My code

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int largest_prime_factor(int a);
int check_prime(int b);

int main() {
    int t; 
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++) {
        long n; 
        scanf("%ld", &n);
        printf("%d\n", largest_prime_factor(n));
    }
    return 0;
}

int largest_prime_factor(int a) {
    if (check_prime(a) != 1) {
        for (int i = a - 1; i > 1; i--) {
           if (a % i == 0) {
                a = i;
           }
        }
        
        largest_prime_factor(a);
   }
   else {
       return a;
   }
}

int check_prime(int b) {
    int s = (int)sqrt(b);
    for (int i = 2; i <= s; i++) {
        if (b % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the compiler error says the problem is; in `largest_prime_factor` function you don't have a return in all paths, and since the return value is used by the calling function all paths must have a return value ( Thanks to @EricPostpischil for pointing out the proper standard rule) .  In one case of the `if` you call recursively and don't have a return value for when the recursion completes. In the other pathway you return `a`. You need a return in all pathways.

more visually:

```
int largest_prime_factor(int a) {
    if (check_prime(a) != 1) {
        for (int i = a - 1; i > 1; i--) {
           if (a % i == 0) {
                a = i;
           }
        }
        
        largest_prime_factor(a);
        // You need to return something here perhaps return largest_prime_factor(a)
   }
   else {
       return a;
   }
}
```

Comment: like ```return largest_prime_factor(a);```?

Comment: sure. but I was trying to let him figure out how to solve the problem :-)

Comment: But at one point of time, The loop breaks and it goes to else right?

Comment: Why was I not getting any warnings or errors in other compilers?

Comment: Eventually yes, but that doesnt matter for the rules of the C language. Every pathway through the function must have a non void return.  If your code ever doesnt take the the else it will never return anything as written.

Comment: @UpAndAdam  Ooops...  My bad.  I apologize for being an idiot.

Comment: I don't know, and honestly I don't really care. That's a seperate question for the language lawyers.  Ultimately your code was wrong and wouldn't work. Without knowing exactly what compiler and flags you were using I couldnt even begin to venture a guess, but that doesnt mean there wasnt an issue.  If you were using a C++ compiler for example it can default that to be a return of 0 for you IIRC but that would also not be good.

Comment: @ewokx it's all good. I know you didnt mean any harm :-)

Comment: Lesson you hopefully learned from this is that before you submit your code you should try running it and testing it.  If you had done either of those things before submitting you probably would have seen something was very wrong with your code and could have fixed it yourself which will help you progress as a programmer.

Comment: @Shashaank, Re "*Why was I not getting any warnings or errors in other compilers?*", Warnings are mostly compiler-specific. Maybe the other compilers don't have a warning for this, or maybe you didn't ask for warnings about this.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: Re “… the rules of the C language. Every pathway through the function must have a non void return”: The C standard does not require every path through a function with a non-void return type to return a value. The behavior is not defined by the C standard only if the function returns without returning a value (by flowing to its closing `}`) **and** the calling function attempts to use the return value (which OP’s program does, so they need a `return`, but not every program does).

Comment: @UpAndAdam: Re “Lesson you hopefully learned from this is that before you submit your code you should try running it and testing it. If you had done either of those things before submitting you probably would have seen something was very wrong with your code”: First, where does OP say anything about having submitted their code? You are chastising them for doing something there is no evidence they did…

Comment: … Second, why do you think testing would reveal an error? The `return a;` in the base case will put `a` in the register used for returning an `int`. In the path with `largest_prime_factor(a);`, there is no C code between that call and the return (by flowing to the closing `}`), so the compiler will likely not generate any instructions before the function return, thus leaving the return register unchanged. The final effect is likely to be as if the code were `return largest_prime_factor(a);`, and then testing would not reveal any problem…

Comment: … I did actually test with Clang (Apple Clang 11 with `-O3`), and it behaved as I described.

Comment: @EricPostpischil read the post before the edits i made to remove that unimportant information regarding submitting.  originally it said I had submitted this to hackerrank.
The testing would reveal an error because if they ever took the if branch nothing would ever be returned and its completely compiler defined as to what happens, the compiler could optimize the whole thing out.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you for the language lawyer correction regarding the C standard and the actual rules about returns, I knew there was some gotcha but I never bother to remember it because I find it to be bad practice and breaks the principals of least surprise and contract design. If you say a function is non-void you should return something in all paths, and said return value should be checked or used.  Proper unit testing would test such cases to provide proper code coverage.  Concede to your statement being correct, that's why I said leave it for the language lawyers (and up voted it)

Comment: @UpAndAdam: Re “The testing would reveal an error because if they ever took the if branch nothing would ever be returned and its completely compiler defined as to what happens, the compiler could optimize the whole thing out”: No, revealing the error is not what happens. As I informed you, I tested this with Clang, and the behavior with `largest_prime_factor(a);` is the same as the behavior with `return largest_prime_factor(a);`. While the C standard might allow anything to happen here, what happens is that the compiler merely leaves the previously returned value in the return register.

Comment: Incorrect, that's what happens on *your* compiler his generated an error and wouldn't compile the code.  Clearly compilers can behave differently or aren't following the standard ( which they are quite often known to do ).  Does the standard specify what should happen? If it does cite it.  Maybe you are right.  I don't understand your goal. Why are you arguing so much about a comment.  Are you saying that testing it more is a bad thing?  Are you saying that someone should submit code anywhere without checking that it compiles first? That testing is bad advice?